# Generating Random Password with numerous arrays using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, password-generator

I am having trouble trying to work out how to complete my random password generator.
Hopefully someone can give me some advice?

```js
var upperCase = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
var lowerCase = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
var specialCharacters = ['`', '~', '!', '@', '#', '%']
```

Retrieving user chosen password parameters:

```js
var lowercaseAnswer = confirm("Do you want lowercase letters?");
var uppercaseAnswer = confirm("Do you want uppercase letters?");
var specialCharactersAnswer = confirm("Do you want special characters?");
    
function generatePassword(){
  var passwordInfo = getPasswordInfo()
     if (specialCharactersAnswer = true) {
        allOptions.push(specialCharacters);
     }
     if (uppercaseAnswer = true) {
        allOptions.push(upperCase);
     }
 
  var passwordInfo = {
    length : sizeOfPassword,
    hasSpecial : specialCharactersAnswer,
    hasNumeric : numericalAnswer,
    hasLowercase: lowercaseAnswer,
    hasUppercase : uppercaseAnswer,
  }
  
  return passwordInfo;
}
```

Generating the password:

```js
var passwordInfo = getPasswordInfo()
    function passwordInfo () {
      for (i = 0; i < sizeOfPassword.length; i++) {
         var writePassword = allOptions[Math.floor(allOptions.length * Math.random())];
      document.write(writePassword);
}
```

Assignment Code:

```js
var generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");
```

Write password to the `#password` input:

```js
function writePassword() {
   var password = getPasswordInfo();
   var passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");
    
   passwordText.value = password;
}
```

Add event listener to generate button:

```js
generateBtn.addEventListener("click", writePassword);
```

Comment: And the problem is? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: _"how to complete"_ is not something we can answer really? What issues are you facing? What output are you getting? What output do you wish to get?